# why is some code in italics in Android studio

Tags: android

For example:

File myFile = Environment.*getExternalStorageDirectory*();

What is the significance of the function name in italic?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is italic because the method is static. You don't need to create a new Instance of Environment to call the getExternalStorageDirectory() function.